# Replace and change several items in string

Tags: python, regex

I have a list and a string like this

```
lst = ['A bce12#','BBC%$','FGC SD!']
txt = "A bce12# and some more texts BBC%$ and again some more texts FGC SD! "
```

And I am looking for a output that all special characters is removed from the string.

```
output = "Abce12 and some more texts BBC and again some more texts FGCSD "
```

I have tried a few approaches. But this is the one that I believe is more likely to be the correct approach, but it gives  me error. Any idea, or other suggestions?

```
def remove_juks(string):
    lst = ['A bce12#','BBC%$','FGC SD!']
    big_regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, lst)))
    output = big_regex.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(string))
    return output

print(remove_juks(txt))
```

Error:

```
sentence = big_regex.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', str(string))

TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What error does it give you?  Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Hi I am getting TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Then you should read up in the documentation of `sub`.

Answer (score 1):

You could handle each of the items in `lst` individually:

```
for l in lst:
    txt = txt.replace( l, re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', l) )
print(txt)
```

prints

```
Abce12 and some more texts BBC and again some more texts FGCSD
```

using Python 3.